# for loop filling array[0] but thats it

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The aim of the for loop is to create a new currentJob for each line of text from the file and store it in an array. The loop stores the first line of text but doesn't store anything else.

```
public static void job()
{
    File file = new File("DailyJobs.txt");

    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

            Job[] jobArray = new Job[30];

            for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.length; i++)
            {
                Job currentJob = new Job();

                int jID = lineScanner.nextInt();
                int cID = lineScanner.nextInt();
                String rego = lineScanner.next();
                String date = lineScanner.next();
                String day = lineScanner.next();
                double fee = lineScanner.nextDouble();

                int[] sc = new int[4];
                int f = 0;
                while(lineScanner.hasNextInt())
                {
                    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
                    sc[f] = (lineScanner.nextInt());
                    f++;
                }

                currentJob.setJobID(jID);
                currentJob.setCustomerID(cID);
                currentJob.setRegistration(rego);
                currentJob.setDate(date);
                currentJob.setDay(day);
                currentJob.setTotalFee(fee);
                currentJob.setServiceCode(sc);

                jobArray[i] = currentJob;


                System.out.println(currentJob.getJobID());
                System.out.println(currentJob.getCustomerID());
                System.out.println(currentJob.getRegistration());
                System.out.println(currentJob.getDate());
                System.out.println(currentJob.getDay());
                System.out.println(currentJob.getTotalFee());
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currentJob.getServiceCode()));

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jobArray));



            }


        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

``
This what I'm getting at the moment

```
90301
14304
ITGURU
11/11/2014
Tuesday
735.75
[1204, 1205, 0, 0]
[Job@1c31e2ad, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

90301 down to [1204, 1205, 0, 0] is the contents of the line. As you can see it's storing the first line of the text file and then nothing. I need help to fix this.

Completely forgot about the catch statement being empty but yes it's showing some issues

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at test3.job(test3.java:31)
    at test3.main(test3.java:9)
```

The above is what I'm getting.

DailyJobs.txt

```
90301,14304,ITGURU,11/11/2014,Tuesday,735.75,1204,1205
90302,14314,ROK5TR,12/11/2014,Wednesday,335.75,1205
90303,14318,HRTBRK,13/11/2014,Thursday,125.5,1200
90304,14310,EVOH8R,14/11/2014,Friday,1207.95,1211
90305,14300,G4MER,11/11/2014,Tuesday,500,1204,1202
90306,14312,COFFEE,11/11/2014,Tuesday,100,1202
90307,14316,POPULR,11/11/2014,Tuesday,150,1203
90308,14317,WRXSTI,11/11/2014,Tuesday,1307.95,1211,1202
90309,14321,FAST,11/11/2014,Tuesday,400,1204
90310,14308,PRQUL8,14/11/2014,Friday,150,1203
90311,14315,OK2BL8,14/11/2014,Friday,335.75,1205
90312,14320,OLDGUY,11/11/2014,Tuesday,1207.95,1211
90313,14313,ABC123,12/11/2014,Wednesday,,1202,1203,1205,1210
90314,14306,WAIT,11/11/2014,Tuesday,150,1203
90315,14302,FUZZ,14/11/2014,Friday,335.75,1205
90316,14313,GO,12/11/2014,Wednesday,,1204,1202
90317,14309,SING,13/11/2014,Thursday,400,1204
90318,14307,MANIC,12/11/2014,Wednesday,100,1202
90319,14305,URABUS,14/11/2014,Friday,1207.95,1211
90320,14303,STOP,14/11/2014,Friday,150,1203
90321,14310,BAKOFF,11/11/2014,Tuesday,,1204,1205
90322,14322,WINNER,14/11/2014,Friday,1207.95,1211
90323,14324,KITTY,13/11/2014,Thursday,400,1204
90324,14325,WEDDIN,12/11/2014,Wednesday,100,1202
90325,14326,FIGHTR,11/11/2014,Tuesday,100,1202
90326,14320,OLDGUY,14/11/2014,Friday,175.9,1208
90327,14322,QUICK,12/11/2014,Wednesday,,1203,1204,1209
90328,14322,L8R,13/11/2014,Thursday,400,1204
90329,14299,TRUTH,13/11/2014,Thursday,80.25,1197
90330,14337,NIGHT,13/11/2014,Thursday,150,1203
90331,14312,COFFEE,13/11/2014,Thursday,350,1204
```

Comment: Well, you should get this block of console prints 30 times. Check if the last print shows a full `jobArray`.

Comment: You probably have an `Exception` being thrown up but since you don't print anything in your `catch` statement it looks like the program ends normally. Add a `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` statement and show us the result.

Comment: never ignore exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the exception `NoSuchElementException` occures here:

```
int jID = lineScanner.nextInt();
```

This means, the scanner tries to read an int, that is not there. The main problem is your current code structure:

```
int jID = lineScanner.nextInt();
int cID = lineScanner.nextInt();
String rego = lineScanner.next();
String date = lineScanner.next();
String day = lineScanner.next();
double fee = lineScanner.nextDouble();

// omitted code
while(lineScanner.hasNextInt())
{
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    sc[f] = (lineScanner.nextInt());
    f++;
}
```

You're reading some stuff and assigning it to variables, then you're reading until the last integer (`lineScanner.hasNextInt()`). This loop will stop if there is no more integer to read available. After that, you're doing more stuff that is not necessary here.

This was the first iteration of `for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.length; i++)`. Now comes the next iteration. The `lineScanner` is still the same, therefore there is integer to read due to the loop `while(lineScanner.hasNextInt())`, but the second iteration will reach the line `int jID = lineScanner.nextInt();`. The scanner tries to read an int, can't find something to read and throws an `NoSuchElementException`.

To fix that, you should reset your `lineScanner` to read a new line.
Or delete the `for` loop, because the `while(scanner.hasNextLine())` will take care of reading each available line and your `lineScanner` will be "filled" correctly. And please re-think the current position of your variable `Job[] jobArray = new Job[30];`. You'll lost his data on each new line of your file.

Comment: while(lineScanner.hasNextInt())
{
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    sc[f] = (lineScanner.nextInt());
    f++;
}
is being used for my ServiceCode setter, should I change the name of the scanner?

Comment: @Ashleigh This loop reads the remaining integers from the current line (and this will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there more than 4 values there). After that loop, the read pointer will be on the end of the line. Therefore it is nothing more to read if your code reaches `int jID = lineScanner.nextInt();` the second time.

Comment: Should I make the array 2D to better accommodate the ServiceCode array instead of the way I've done it?

Answer (score 2):

You should put

```
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
```

in your for loop.

Comment: Place System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jobArray)); outside the for loop simply made it not print anything.

Comment: That means that your code is interrupted and stopped somewhere in your for loop.  Can you add the lines off code in which an error is given?

Comment: It's telling me int jID = lineScanner.nextInt(); is causing problems

Comment: Can you add your DailyJobs.txt, i think that is causing the problems

Comment: I've added the text file